# Sencha touch, Show details when selecting master objects' item

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.2

Hi I am new to Sencha touch. i m using the Sencha architect IDE
I want to show in mobile app, List of Authors and Quotes. I want to show quotes list of **selected** author in another list. To show the Authors list its no problem. But show quotes panel/list when selecting is problem for me. I have tried to create new view/detail panel, then added an action in controller but nothing.
Please refer me any tutorial for sencha..

Data stores are JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial you want is here:

http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/guide/first_app

Stay focus on the "Blog" features. It follows master-details pattern.

Regarding your application, I have no idea since you have not uploaded any relevant source code.

Comment: Thank you for post answer, i need a tutorial that represents masterLisrt - detailsList orientation..

Comment: isn't it something you need?